# SVN setup on semi-dedicated server (Linux)

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I'm going through the process of setting up SVN on my remote web server (Linux Centos), and I'm needing a bit of help to make sure I do it correctly. So far I've installed SVN and used svnadmin create to set up a repo at /home/repos. The plan would be to set up projects within /home/repos e.g /home/repos/project1 etc. I've also edited subversion.conf
 as follows:

```
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn   
    SVNParentPath /home/repos
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repos"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
    Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

I then set up my auth file in /etc/svn-auth-conf.

This is my first bash at setting up SVN and I want to set it up on the web server so that I can checkout web projects to my laptop to do development work, then make commits back to the server.  Am I going the right way about it? I'm a solo developer and don't want anything overly complicated as this stage.

Also, I get a 404 when I try and navigate to http://webserverIP/~repos/ - not sure why this is happening...usually this is how I access different accounts I've set up on the server.

Comment: What happens when you try to hit http://webserverIP/repos/ ?

Comment: Voting to migrate to serverfault.com

Comment: I get a 404...strange. The location is /home/repos - not sure what i'm missing

Answer (score 4):

`SVNParentPath` is a directory where you store your repositories, it is not a repo itself.
Create a repo inside like `/home/repos/project1` - and not in `/home/repos` itself.

As your Location is `/repos` access it like http://webserverIP/repos/project1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bring to your attention the possibility of using svn+ssh instead of http.  Once you set up your private/public keys, you won't have to type in passwords unless you set up one on your ssh agent.  You will also not need to run a web server, just your ssh server which I assume you already have running.

Check out [this page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) and look for tunneling over SSH.